# files disappear upon umount

Tags: filesystems, mount, sd-card, e2fsck

I have a mystery ... a reproducibile one, but still a mystery.

My ideapad 100s has a SD card reader which I use to store stuff while I work on it, as its built-in drive is super tiny. Its really just a temporary use, because I normally git push stuff quite frequently.

This has worked for sometime, but now stuff that I add to this SD card filesystem disappears at the time of umount. All the files I did put before are still there, it's just the new stuff that disappears. It happens all the times I do `umount`.

I have tried to issue `sync .` in the new folder, I have also tried to change a bit the `fstab` line for this SD card, but cannot solve this.

I noted that in `dmesg` there is a message about the filesystem

```
[Sun Dec 10 19:34:48 2023] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p1): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
[Sun Dec 10 19:34:48 2023] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
```

and I did try a simple `e2fsck` and it insists that it was not cleanly unmounted even after repeating.

```
sudo e2fsck /dev/mmcblk1p1 
e2fsck 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
/dev/mmcblk1p1 was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/mmcblk1p1: 18783/15622144 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 17101516/62459904 blocks
```

The exit code is 1, which means it has corrected errors according to the man page of e2fs. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: My bets are on an SD card that has reached the end of its life and now is just dropping writes. Try a different card?

Comment: Does this happen on more than one SD card? It could be the one you are using is failing

Comment: I have considered this, but how can I test this hypothesis? For the record this a barely used card, few months old and used only very little. Besides it is a "heavy duty" one, [WD Purple](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/memory-cards/wd-purple-microsd?sku=WDD032G1P0C)

Comment: Flash is extremely cheaply produced, so hardware issues like this are very common. Try on another operating system. Try running `sync` before unmounting.

Comment: I have tried `sync` already, but it does not help.

Comment: I finally managed to look at the total amount written. This is a 256 Gb card and dume2fs reports Lifetime writes: 66 GB. Not even written all its capacity.